# Question about this use of the conditional form

Tags: grammar, translation, conditionals, dialogue

I'm trying to understand an exchange:

A: まともに行ってもここを通り抜けるのはキツイがな

B: 見りゃぁわかるぜ

In this case person B starts their sentence with a contraction of the conditional form of 見る, but I'm not sure why. It's my understanding that the verb that precedes the "ば" is the "If [X]", part, so would this sentence just mean "If I can see that, I understand it"? The subtitles translate it as just "I can see that", so I'm just a little confused why the conditional and "wakaruze" are even needed here.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, incorrect or unnatural about B's comment 「見{み}りゃぁわかるぜ」.  That is just a native speaker speaking Japanese like a native speaker should be.

It is only the ***literal translation*** "If I see it, I understand." that is making it look like a strange thing to say.

My own free translations would be:

"You can tell by looking at it."

"It only takes one look."

"Tell me about it!"

"That's for sure!"

"Obviously!"

It gets shorter and shorter.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks.

Knowing "You can tell by looking at it" is a valid translation helps me understand the feeling a little better.